# Powershell. Use PSCredential to view a secure string. Is this technique secure?

Tags: powershell, read-host

There are many posts on viewing and comparing secureString objects. Many use .Net's Marshal method, which even its advocates admit is convoluted. A quicker method involves placing the secure string into a PSCredential object and using the GetNetworkCredential() method. Example below:

```
$ssn = Read-Host("Enter your social security number") -AsSecureString
$ssn
"You entered $clearText = $((New-Object PSCredential($ssn,'.')).GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
```

The second line outputs:

```
System.Security.SecureString
```

The third line outputs:

```
You entered 123456789
```

This is a nice little hack. I can use -AsSecureString to (1)obscure the user's input on the screen and (2) keep the string encrypted in memory. And I can also decrypt the SecureString for String methods (check length, validate input, compare to another secure string).

Is this still secure? Certainly at the moment "GetNetworkCredential()" is called, there's a decrypted string in memory. Is that string/pointer removed after the method completes? Or does it sit in memory until garbage collection erases it?

Comment: On your variable definition, `-As Securehost` is redundant. If you do `As` it will already encrypt it, when you add the extra `securehost` it prompts `Enter your social security number SecureHost:`.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo.